# Meteor App.configurePlugin and Cordova corner case

Tags: cordova, meteor, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

i've installed a cordova plugin with the usual syntax

```
meteor add cordova:cc.fovea.cordova.purchase@3.10.1
```

this plugin requires a configuration setting that i've done with

```
App.configurePlugin('cordova:cc.fovea.cordova.purchase', {
  BILLING_KEY : MY_KEY
});
```

and it works.

Now i want to try a most recent version of this one so accordingly to [THIS](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Meteor-Cordova-Phonegap-integration#using-cordova-%20plugins-directly-in-your-application) i've installed a tarball with

```
meteor add cordova:cc.fovea.cordova.purchase@https://github.com/j3k0/cordova-plugin-purchase/tarball/2b75e86979b1cc24aaa87ad4c15a77414f70269e
```

and it works **BUT** when i try to build my app with meteor build i've the following error

```
Error while building for mobile platforms: Error running                           
/Users/giggioz/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1ui9e5i++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/cordova-scripts/cordova.sh
Failed to install 'cc.fovea.cordova.purchase':Error: Variable(s) missing: BILLING_KEY
at
/Users/giggioz/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1ui9e5i++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/install.js:304:23
at _fulfilled (/Users/giggioz/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1ui9e5i++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:787:54)
at self.promiseDispatch.done
(/Users/giggioz/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1ui9e5i++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:816:30)
at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch
(/Users/giggioz/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1ui9e5i++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:749:13)
at /Users/giggioz/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1ui9e5i++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:557:44
at flush (/Users/giggioz/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1ui9e5i++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)
at process._tickCallback (node.js:442:13)
Error: Variable(s) missing: BILLING_KEY
at
/Users/giggioz/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1ui9e5i++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/install.js:304:23
at _fulfilled (/Users/giggioz/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1ui9e5i++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:787:54)
at self.promiseDispatch.done
(/Users/giggioz/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1ui9e5i++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:816:30)
at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch
(/Users/giggioz/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1ui9e5i++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:749:13)
at /Users/giggioz/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1ui9e5i++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:557:44
at flush (/Users/giggioz/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1ui9e5i++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)
at process._tickCallback (node.js:442:13)


Installing "cc.fovea.cordova.purchase" for android
```

As you can see it seems like it does not see the configuration setting of my

```
App.configurePlugin('cordova:cc.fovea.cordova.purchase', {
      BILLING_KEY : MY_KEY
    });
```

Can you figure out why this error?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could [this](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/4234) be related? Did you try to remove `.meteor/local/cordova-build` like they mention? I know it should still have the value, just not update it... but it's worth a try

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use this line to configure your build plugin:

```
App.configurePlugin('cc.fovea.cordova.purchase', {
  BILLING_KEY : MY_KEY
});
```

Not sure if it will work but it may.